# why link to redundant dynamic library

Tags: linux

in linux(kylin), i create a process(pro) which linked to some .so. on some machines, it works very well. but it can't run on one machine. i use ldd to check the process,
ldd pro
it link to many redundant .so. the redundant .so are  written by other programmers.

i set up the system variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH, make sure that it only include the paths that contain the so i needed.  then compile can't pass.(i also try this on other machines, it compile ok.)

i really confused about that why my codes are mixed with other programmer's codes.

i'm the first time to ask question, thanks everyone who view the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "other programmer's codes"? The libraries that you use, did you write them all yourself? How about the libraries the libraries depend on? And so on? Did you write the Linux kernel and user-space all yourself? The amount of code written by you that you run is a small fraction of a fraction of a percent of all the code running on your system at any given moment.

Comment: “other programer's codes"  means that they are not system code.  some of the dynamic libraries my process depandes on  are  written by me，some are open dynamic libraries.

Answer (score 0):

today, i solved  this problem.

first, i wrote a "helloworld" program, it still linked to others dynamic libraries. such as "xxx.so not found, it is needed by /usr/lib64/crti.o"

then, i check the file 'crti.o', it is really modified by other programmers. it linked so many dynamic libraries.

after i replace this file by other machine, everything works well.